# Node React js value gets overidden when updating from child component

Tags: reactjs, node.js

I have a simple app where a List of objects(json) is grabed from a file and then used in usestate. The this is passed to a component where an input boc binds one property of the sent object and an onchange is fired to call parent's method to set the value in the main List.

**App.js**

```
import ClientDetails from '../component/ClientDetails';
import './App.css';
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState , useRef } from 'react';
import configdetails from '../appdata/configdetails.json';
import clientdetails from '../appdata/clientdetails.json';

let isLoading = true;

function App() {
  let [clientdata, setclientdata] = useState([]);
  
  console.log(configdetails);
  console.log(clientdetails);
  
  useEffect(() => {
      /*fetch("/init")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setclientdata(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));
        
        isLoading = false;
      });*/  

      isLoading = false;
      setclientdata(clientdetails);
      //setclientdata(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(clientdetails)));
  },[]);

  let bindVaraible = (event, dt, prnm, ind) =>{
    //let l_clientdata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, dt))); 
    let l_clientdata = clientdata[ind];
    ind = parseInt(ind);
    l_clientdata[prnm] = event.target.value;
    
    console.log(clientdata.length + '>>>' + ind);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(clientdata));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(l_clientdata));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(clientdata[ind]));
    
    clientdata[ind] = l_clientdata;
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(clientdata));
    
    //setclientdata(clientdata);
  }

  if (isLoading) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p className="App-intro">tttt {JSON.stringify(clientdata)}</p>
        <ClientDetails localclientdata={clientdata[0]} indexvar="0" bindVaraible={bindVaraible}/>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Component.js**

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function ClientDetails({localclientdata, indexvar, bindVaraible}) {
  return (
        <span>
          <p className="App-intro">tttt {JSON.stringify(localclientdata)}</p>
          <input value={localclientdata.access_token} onChange={e => { bindVaraible(e, localclientdata, "access_token", indexvar); }} type="text" />
        </span>
  );
}

export default ClientDetails;
```

The issue: when I type any value in the input it fires the event and value can be traced in the console but the clientdata via setclientdata() remians as is.